# For the 2nd movie of Fairy Tail: Dragon Cry, at what moment is it placed?

Tags: fairy-tail

With what happened in the second season, Fairy Tail disbanded and Natsu went on an adventure to train. In that time, Gray got his Ice Devil Slayer Magic which we also see in the movie. Then, when Natsu gets back from his training, he gets everyone together and the master as well. Once that happens, preparations for war and war happen in season 3. At the end of season 3, Hisui becomes queen/ruler of Fiore. In *Dragon Cry*, Hisui is not the queen of the land, meaning that we can presume that it was before season 3.

With all of this, at what moment in the Fairy Tail timeline was all of this place in? Gray has his Ice Devil Slayer Magic which he got from the battle with the 9 gates which Fairy Tail disbanded after the battle. Hisui is not the ruler of Fiore which happens at the end of season 3. During the whole season 3, Fairy Tail is battling Zeref's empire leaving no time to go on a quest.

Answer (score 1):

I think it took place after the actual series end because in Dragon Cry, Natsu has a lot of moments where he seems to know that he’s E.N.D and asks Lucy “what do I look like to you?”.
But I am not 100% sure of that as this is the only point I can think of as for.

Answer (score 1):

It does take place near the end of the series because it is not at the end because that is the beginning of fairy tail 100 years quest.